# Vue js 3 use multiple custom classes on table dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a project where i use vue for my frontend, but i am new on vue. And i am trying to add some dynamically `class` on my table. So  for example where i check `table-sm` table will assing this class. Already i have done this but it work only with one class. I really dont know how to do this to work with an array. Can someone help ?

I want also to add another input for other classes EX: `table-bordered` and `table-striped` ...

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input v-model="smallTable.active" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="smallTable" @change="tableStyles()">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="smallTable">
    Small Table
  </label>
</div>

//Table tag
<table class="table table-hover align-middle mb-0" :class="smallTable.smTable">
...

//vue component
data() {
        return {
        smallTable: {smTable: "", active: false,},
      }
}

tableStyles() {
            if (this.smallTable.active) {
                this.smallTable.smTable = "table-sm"
            }else {
                this.smallTable.smTable = ""
            }
            localStorage.setItem("tableStyle", JSON.stringify(this.smallTable));
        },
```

what i am loking for is something like this:

```
data() {
        return {
        smallTable: [
          {smTable: "", active: false,},
          {bordertable: "", active: false,}
         ]
      }
}
```

Comment: It's easy! just put your classes in a row `this.smallTable.smTable = "table-sm table-class2 tbl-class3"`

Comment: No, manybe you missunderstood me .I dont want this. I want multiple `input type="checkbox"` where i can chose different classe i want to add on my table. One checkbox for `table-sm` one for `table-bordered` and some other class maybe

Comment: I fixed my answer. It gives you the idea. Use your real names instead, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. Using a string of classes that separated by space

```js
tableStyles() {
  this.smallTable.smTable = '';
  if (this.smallTable.active) {
    this.smallTable.smTable += ' table-sm';
  }
  if (this.checkbox1.active) {
    this.smallTable.smTable += ' table-bordered';
  }
  if (this.checkbox2.active) {
    this.smallTable.smTable += ' table-hover';
  }
  localStorage.setItem('tableStyle', JSON.stringify(this.smallTable));
},
```

2. Using an object of classes by according boolean switch

```js
// You are supposed to create an object
// whose keys are the class names and
// values are boolean showing how a class should apply or not.

tableStyles() {
  this.smallTable.smTable = {
    'table-sm':       this.smallTable.active,
    'table-bordered': this.checkbox1.active,
    'table-hover':    this.checkbox2.active,
  };
  localStorage.setItem('tableStyle', JSON.stringify(this.smallTable));
},
```

It gives you the idea of how to set classes dynamically. Please tune conditions according to your actual data.

Comment: So if i do this, where i check the checkbox 3 this classes will add on my table tag. But this is not what i want. I want multiple checkbox, For example: 3 input checkbox will have each by this class, so when i click first checkobx i want to assing only first class, not all 3 cass

Comment: So, in this case, you need to use Radio Buttons instead of Checkboxes.

Comment: I dont waht to use `radio` couse maybe i need to check multiple classes, ex: `table-sm` and `table-bordered` in same time. But this should be with 2 differend checkboxes. I have updated my questions

Comment: Imagine a situation where every 3 checkboxes are active. Which classes do you want to apply to?

Comment: If 3 checkboxes are active: `table-sm, table-bordered, table-hover`. I think this is a good combination. I just want to let users to personalize his table, so this is the reason i save this on `localstorage`

Comment: OK. I tuned class names in the answer. Another question: How do you detect that checkboxes are active? For example, this `this.smallTable.active` shows me the state of the first check box.  I'm looking for the state of other checkboxes.

Comment: `input v-model="smallTable.active"` can do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247173/discussion-between-mr-r-and-leoon0012).

Answer (score 0):

you can  use `ternary condition` in class binding to binding multiple class for an element
read more abou it [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/ternary+operator+in+vuejs+class)

Comment: Can you do an example with mu code? I am not understanding how it work. I need to add multiple input but for differenc classes

Comment: So I probably did not understand your question correctly